# McDiarmid's Inequality for random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

Let $\boldsymbol{X}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a random vector and  $\boldsymbol{X}^{(1)},\boldsymbol{X}^{(2)},...,\boldsymbol{X}^{(n)}$ are  $n$ independent observations. Also $f: \mathbb{R}^{d\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $|f(\boldsymbol{X}^{(1)},\boldsymbol{X}^{(2)},...,\boldsymbol{X}^{(i)},...,\boldsymbol{X}^{(n)})-f(\boldsymbol{X}^{(1)},\boldsymbol{X}^{(2)},...,\boldsymbol{X'}^{(i)},...,\boldsymbol{X}^{(n)})|\leq c_i$. Is it true that :

$\text{Pr}[|f-\mathbb{E}f| \geq\epsilon] \leq 2 \exp(\frac{-2\epsilon ^2}{\sum _i c^2_i}) $ ? Notice that the elemements of $\boldsymbol{X}$ are not independent.

Comment: It seems like your title "McDiarmid's inequality" answers the question.  Are you concerned about "random vector" versus "random variable"? If you like, any random vector can be measurably mapped with 1-1 correspondence to a random variable.  Alternatively, I don't think anything in the proof of McDiarmid would change if "random variable" were replaced by "random vector."

Comment: I am concerned because I can write the function $f$ as a function $g: \mathbb{R}^{d \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ as $g(X^{(1)}_{1}, X^{(1)}_{2},....,,X^{(1)}_{d},X^{(2)}_{1},....,,X^{(2)}_{d},..., X^{(n)}_{d} )$ then then Mcdiarmid's cant be applied since the $n \times d$ observations are not all independent. Maybe my intuition is wrong, but I was looking for a way to convert the problem to the classical McDiarmid's inequality statement.

Comment: Writing it that way does not seem helpful.  Your $c_i$ bounds are in terms of changing the random vectors singly, so writing it that way, it would involve changing groups of components.  What is wrong with a 1-1 mapping $\vec{X}_i \leftrightarrow Y_i$ as in my first comment?  So $Y_i = h(\vec{X}_i)$ and $\vec{X}_i = h^{-1}(Y_i)$.

Comment: I guess the 1-1 mapping is fine, and yes $c_{i}$ should be different. I will go over the proof of McDiarmid's tomorrow for practice. Thank you sir!

Comment: ^Since I was wondering the same this just a couple of months ago, yes, what you have is indeed correct. All McD. needs is that $f$ is real valued, since (the standard) proof is based on the martingale $\{\mathbb{E}[f | X_1, \dots, X_k]\}_{ k \le n}$. Applying this gets a little hairy, though, since you now require a stronger notion of bounded differences (instead of changing just one variable, I can change any entry in a vector and the differences should still be bounded). This typically weakens the concentration, although how significant that is context-dependent.